# UIAlertView Crash after back button and dispatch_async complete

Tags: ios, uialertview

i have a view embedded on UINavigationController.
On this view a i have a button forward to UITableViewController.
When i arrived on UITableViewController on UINavigationcontroler i add a button for upload a file.
The file upload operation is performed inside dispatch_async.
When dispatch_async complete i add a UIAlertView with message complete.
There is a problem, because i back button from UINavigationController and dispatch_async is not complete, my app crash.
Where am I doing wrong?
After my code
Thanks,
Vincenzo

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^ {

    BOOL                    success;
    NSURL *                 url;
    NSString *fileNameUrl = [@"ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/" stringByAppendingString:nameFile];
    url = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance]smartURLForString:fileNameUrl];
    success = (url != nil);

    if ( ! success) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid URL");
    } else {
        self.fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:dataAsset];
        assert(self.fileStream != nil);

        [self.fileStream open];
        self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                                               CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)
                                               );
        success = [self.networkStream setProperty:@"XXXX" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
        success = [self.networkStream setProperty:@"YYYYYY" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
        self.networkStream.delegate = self;
        [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [self.networkStream open];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]run];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SUCCESS" message:@"Complete" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the alert's delegate to `self`. Set it to `nil`.

The problem you have by using `self` is that the delegate tries to contact its delegate after the button is tapped but `self` is no longer valid because you dismissed the view controller.